# How do I pass a url from a Jinja2 template to a Flask app route / function whea a parameter contains whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I would like to pass a parameter to a Flask app from a Jinja2 template that contains white space. In the example below I am trying to pass Dallas Cowboys.

template

```
{% set homeTeam = 'Dallas Cowboys'%}
{% set league = 'nfl' %}
{% set sport = 'football' %}

{% set url = '/details/' + sport + '/' + league + '/' + homeTeam %}
<a href={{url}}>{{time_formatted}} - {{homeTeam}} vs. {{awayTeam}}</a>
             
<a href={{url}}>Click Me</a>
```

What I want here is:

```
<a href="/details/football/nfl/dallas%20cowboys>Click Me</a>
```

What I get is:

```
<a href="/details/football/nfl/dallas" cowboys ="">Click Me</a>
```

I want to be able to print "Dallas Cowboys" in the Flask function below:

app

```
@app.route('/details/<sport>/<league>/<home_team>')
    def details(sport, league, home_team):
        print(sport, league, home_team) #I need "Dallas Cowbows" for home_team
        return render_template('details.html', sport=sport, league=league, home_team=home_team)
```

Answer (score 1):

Template

```
<a href='{{url_for('details', sport='football', league='nfl, home_team='Cowboys' > Click </a>
```

This should work , note use url_for , pass all the parameters to backend and thats it.

Comment: I don't think I stated the problem clearly enough so I edited the question. The sport, league, and home_team are all variables.

Comment: @MikeC. Your template code doesn't have quotations when setting the attribute.  `href={{url}}` should be `href="{{url}}"` Without those quotations the browser will treat the first space as the end of the link.